# Calling onclick function for every output from table without refreshing each time

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

I am writing code in which I am displaying data from database here is my code:

```
   while ($resords = $sth->fetchAll()) {
        foreach ($resords as $value) {
            $sqno = $value["sqno"];
            $name = $value ["name"];
            $address = $value["address"];
     $list .= ' <div class="wrapper">
                   <div class="content-main">
                       <a onclick="calculateRoute()"  id="destination" style="text-decoration: none"><h3><strong >' . $name . '</a> </strong></h3>
                          <br></div>
                          <div class="content-secondary"> ' . $address . '</div>
                 </div><hr>';
}
```

It is showing me correct list of data but when I am clicking on link I am not getting correct data I mean it is not showing me correct route which I want while I get correct route when I call from button from other place.

here is my calculateRoute()..

```
function calculateRoute() {

    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var destination = document.getElementById('destination').value;

    if (start == '') {
        start = center;
    }

    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: destination,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}
```

and this is somewhere in my code

```
 var selectBox = document.getElementById('destination');

   addOption(selectBox, data[i]['name'], data[i]['address']);

function addOption(selectBox, text, value) {
    var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
    option.text = text;
    option.value = value;
    selectBox.options.add(option);
}
```

it is doing fine when i am selecting any element from drop-down like

```
 <label for="start">Location : </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="start" >

                        <label for="destination">Destination : </label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="destination" onchange="calculateRoute();"></select>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Display Directions" style="margin-top: 20px" onclick="calculateRoute();">
                        </div>
```

but i want this calculateRoute() function to be called from my php code which i am populating from table.i want to make every table element a link and when it clicked it should show direction box.

Comment: Can you show us the code for `calculateRoute()`?  I'm a little rusty with embedded JS but do you need to terminate that call with a semicolon?  Plus your closing tag for the link `a` needs to move past your closing tags for `h3` and `strong`.

Comment: Is the correct loop dependend on the adress? I assume you're in somekind of loop (while or for) through an array of data. Then you'd need to give the js-function a clue where you are calling it from. like `calculateRoute( '".$address."')"`

Comment: You are creating a bunch of elements with the same `id`; each `id` on a page should be unique. That is one of your problems, you are calling `getElementById` in `calculateRoute`, but since all the rows have a `id` of `"destination"` it will always grab the destination from the first row. You are also trying to use the `.value` of destination, only `input` elements have a `.value` property, destination is an `a` tag, it does not have a `.value`. If you were trying to get the text inside of the `a` tag you should instead use `.textContent`.

Comment: thank you so much,i was getting this problem was not able to resolve this as i am new to java script and html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to do. It looks like you have an
input box where the user can type a starting point, a select box that they can
choose a destination from. This works but you also want them to be able to
click on the name of the route in a list of routes and display the same map
that selecting it out of the form does?

I've altered the HTML that generates the list of routes a little, giving
things more meaningful names. Your original code game each item in the list an
element with an `id` of `destination`. An `id` needs to be unique, every time
you call `getElementById`, the first element in the page with that `id` is
always returned.

Instead of attaching a new event handler to every item in the list, I am going
to use [event
delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/),
this will cut down on memory consumption and also make the code a little
shorter. The way I am doing the event delegation there actually isn't a need
to give an `id` to any of the items in the list of routes.

```
<label for="start">Location : </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="start" >

<label for="destination">Destination : </label>
<select class="form-control" id="destination"></select>
<div class="pull-right">
<input id="get-route" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Display Directions" style="margin-top: 20px">
</div>

<?php

while ($resords = $sth->fetchAll()) {
  foreach ($resords as $value) {
    $sqno = htmlentities($value["sqno"]);
    $name = htmlentities($value ["name"]);
    $address = htmlentities($value["address"]);
    $list .= <<<HEREDOC
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content-main">
    <h3 class="route-name">$name</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content-secondary route-address">
    $address
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
HEREDOC;
  }
}

$list = '<div class="route-list">' . $list . '</div>';

echo $list;
```

As you can see, both the element that holds the name of the route and the one
that holds the address for that route get semantically significant classes.
This will allow us to traverse the DOM to find the address based on where the
name you clicked on is. You will also notice that I used
[htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) for
[XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) protection. It is
important to escape any user generated content. I usually like to escape
anything I pull out of a database, this will protect you if someone
compromises your database and manages to get some malicious markup into it.

```
var doc = document,
  elStart = doc.getElementById('start'),
  elDestination = doc.getElementById('destination'),
  displayRoute =  function (start, destination) {
    var request;
    if (start === '') {
        start = center;
    }
    request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: destination,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  },
  getRoute = function () {
    displayRoute(elStart.value, elDestination.value);
  },
  clickRoute = function (event) {
    var target = event.target,
      destination,
      row;

    if (target.classList.contains('route-name')) {
      row = target.parentNode.parentNode; // Gets the "wrapper" that this
                                                // "route-name" is inside of.
                                                // This is a bit fragile, if any
                                                // nodes are inserted between
                                                // route-name and wrapper it
                                                // will break. To make this less
                                                // fragile, you could use
                                                // jQuery's .closest() method
                                                // instead of pure-DOM methods.
      destination = row.querySelector('route-address').textContent;
      displayRoute(elStart.value, destination);
    }
  };

doc.querySelectorAll('.route-list').addEventListener('click', clickRoute, false);
doc.querySelector('#get-route').addEventListener('click', getRoute, false);
elDestination.addEventListener('change', getRoute, false);
```

This code uses [event
delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/)
to attach one event handler to each element with the class `route-list`. This
listener listens for clicks to elements with the `route-name` class and then
acts when one is clicked. It figures out what address is stored in the
`route-address` element inside the parent `wrapper` element. This handler and
the `getRoute` handler attached to the form elements both call `displayRoute`
which actually displays the map.

As I noted in the comment, finding the `wrapper` element via `.parentNode` is
fragile and could break easily if you were to wrap `route-name` in another
element. Refactoring the code to use jQuery would make it more resilient and a
little shorter.

```
var $ = jQuery,
  elStart = $('#start'),
  elDestination = $('#destination'),
  displayRoute =  function (start, destination) {
    var request;
    if (start === '') {
        start = center;
    }
    request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: destination,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  },
  getRoute = function () {
    displayRoute(elStart.val(), elDestination.val());
  },
  clickRoute = function (event) {
    var row = $(this).closest('wrapper'),
      destination = row.find('.route-address').text();
    displayRoute(elStart.val(), destination);
  };

$('.route-list').on('click', '.route-name', clickRoute); // Passing the
                                                         // .route-name
                                                         // selector does the
                                                         // event delegation.
$('#get-route').on('click', getRoute);
elDestination.on('change', getRoute);
```

When attaching the event handler for `.route-list`, the [`.on`
method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) does the delegation logic for us, 
there is no need for the if statement to to filter on the class name to detect
if the click was on the `.route-name` child, jQuery does it for us and only
fires the `clickRoute` handler if the clicked  element was a `.route-name`
element.

Inside of `clickRoute`, [.closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) goes up the DOM tree until
it finds a `.wrapper` element. This will keep working no matter how many
things you might wrap around `.route-name`. After that, [.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)
drills down and finds the `.route-address` element.